# How to increase radius of particular slice of pie chart in core plot api?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I want to increase radius of particular slice, so that one of slice look bigger and other with the same circle, How to implement this, please help me? Follow the following image.

[image]

Comment: @rmaddy can you tell me how to implement this?

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are asking. Create a mockup and attach it to your question, so we can see what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MikeLischke i edited my question and added image, Please follow and let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot control the slice radius independently for each slice in Core Plot, use a second plot and give it the larger radius. Both plots can use the same data. Implement the `-sliceFillForPieChart:recordIndex:` datasource method for both plots. Return `[NSNull null]` to draw an empty slice at the given index. In your example, return a fill at one index on the larger plot and `NSNull` everywhere else. Do the opposite on the smaller plot.

Comment: can you give me some sample code so that i can more understand?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 2 radii (inner and outer radius) it is not possible to increase the size of a single piece. However, what you can do is to offset a single piece so it stands out:

[image]

For this you can set the radial offset of one or more slices. One way to do this is to bind them to an array controller with the offset values like this:

```
[earningsPlot bind: CPTPieChartBindingPieSliceRadialOffsets
          toObject: earningsPlotRadialOffsets
       withKeyPath: @"arrangedObjects"
           options: nil];
```

Comment: Hi @Mike Lischke thanks for your answer..But i already implemented the offset for slice selection animation. Now my requirement is i want to increase only single slice at run time like above image.If you know anything please help.

Comment: Different radii are not possible at the moment. Open a feature request at GitHub for that and maybe it gets implemented. In fact, what you essentially want is a socalled sunburst chart (http://www.jameswelch.net/seo-sunburst-chart-an-industry-in-one-graph/). I have already created a feature request for that plot type (https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/37).